# What would be a proper naming convention when hiding dependencies behind a facade?

Tags: php, naming-conventions

I've got a class performing some operation, say parsing and it's going to be a public repository. Because there is some complexity to the constructor and it is not important for the end user, I wanted to hide it behind a facade.

```
// interface
interface ParserInterface {
    function parse(string $input): Document;
}

// implementation
class ParserImplementation implements ParserInterface {
    function __construct(
        Normalizer $normalizer,
        Tokenizer $tokenizer,
        Interpreter $interpreter,
        etc.
    ) {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
        $this->tokenizer = $tokenizer;
        $this->interpreter = $interpreter;
    }

    function parse(string $input): Document {
        $normalizedInput = $this->normalizer->normalize($input);
        $tokens = $this->tokenizer->tokenize($normalizedInput);
        return $this->interpreter->interpret($tokens);
    }
}

// facade
class ParserFacade implements ParserInterface {
    private $parser;

    function __construct() {
        $this->parser = new ParserImplementation(
            new Normalizer(),
            new Tokenizer(),
            etc.
        );
    }

    function parse(string $input) {
        return $this->parser->parse($input);
    }
}
```

As you see, there is also an interface there.

Now, for the outside application it is the facade that is the parser. For the co-dependent code, it is the interface that is the parser. And for me developing the above solution, it is the ParserImplementation that is the real parser i.e. it is it that encompasses the whole parsing logic. So now, I'm completely lost as to the proper naming convention.

I'd prefer to name the interface as just Parser and the fasade as something a little stating my intention: CustomParser because the whole is a custom implementation of something that has some standard implementation. But then I can't find a pattern to name the inside class (ParserImplementation in the code above).

Is there a well established practice in that regard?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty subjective, but what I usually do, and what I see most often is something like this:

**Interface**: ParserInterface

**Abstract**: ParserAbstract

**Implementation**: Parser

**Facade**: Named for specific purpose (CsvParser, XmlParser, etc), or something like DefaultParser or GenericParser

If it were me, I would probably handle this with abstraction rather than a facade approach. So I would change the ParserImplementation class to be abstract, and make your ParserFacade extend that class, and just call it Parser. If you wanted to provide a streamlined implementation of *that* class, then you could take the facade route, but there probably wouldn't be a need for that in this case.

```
<?php

// interface
interface ParserInterface
{
    function parse(string $input): Document;
}

// abstract
abstract class ParserAbstract implements ParserInterface
{
    function __construct(
        Normalizer $normalizer,
        Tokenizer $tokenizer,
        Interpreter $interpreter
    )
    {
        $this->normalizer  = $normalizer;
        $this->tokenizer   = $tokenizer;
        $this->interpreter = $interpreter;
    }

    function parse(string $input): Document
    {
        $normalizedInput = $this->normalizer->normalize($input);
        $tokens          = $this->tokenizer->tokenize($normalizedInput);
        return $this->interpreter->interpret($tokens);
    }
}

// Concrete class
class Parser extends ParserAbstract
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            new Normalizer(),
            new Tokenizer(),
            new Interpreter()
        );
    }
}

// Concrete class
class XmlParser extends ParserAbstract
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            new NormalizerXml(),
            new TokenizerXml(),
            new Interpreter()
        );
    }
}
```